# Unable to disable write-caching on Azure Data Disk

Tags: azure

We have a DSv2 azure VM with Windows Server 2012 R2, with a 1TB premium storage virtual disk added.  This will be hosting a marklogic database where it is normally required the write-caching be disabled.  The operating system reports that this can not be done [image: see screenshot]

Is there any way to do it?  Does write caching on this type of virtual disk not pose a problem for databases for some reason? The link that says "how can I change the write-caching setting for this devices" does not function.

Comment: http://www.virtualizationadmin.com/articles-tutorials/microsoft-hyper-v-articles/management/hyper-v-optimization-tips-part1.html

Comment: Looks like that answers my question well. Happy to give you answer credit if you post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found this link helpful, will be glad if it will help you.

http://hyper-v.nu/archives/hvredevoort/2013/07/keeping-your-virtual-active-directory-domain-controllers-safe/